# Prometheus Alertmanager is always sending notifications

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Is there any way for alertmanager to stop firing alerts continuously once one has been triggered?

For example I have set some alerting rules for checking uptime of services. If one of those services is down, then alertmanager will not stop sending alert messages until the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

What you described is an [inhibition rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#inhibit_rule). It can suppress an alert when some other alert is firing. Here is a basic example for recent versions of Alertmanager:

```yaml
# for alerts with equal 'instance' label
- equal: ['instance']
# if one has 'severity' label equal to 'critical'
  source_matchers:
    - severity = critical
# and the other has 'warning'
  target_matchers:
    - severity = warning
# then mute the other one (with severity 'warning')
```

Deprecated old-style:

```yaml
- equal: ['instance']
  source_match:
    severity: critical
  target_match:
    severity: warning
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! I applied the above in the .yml of alertmanager although alert messages keep coming.
I suppose that something must be done in Prometheus side as it seems that every rule that is being feeded to alertmanager from Prometheus is being sent.

Comment: @agelosnm nope, Prometheus will keep sending alerts no matter what. It is up to Alertmanager to decide whether to mail them. I guess it is either rule matchers are not working or, if it is the same alert keeps coming, repeat interval (another setting) is too low.

Comment: ok understood! Indeed, alert interval is 20 seconds. This because is "constantly" checking for uptime.

Comment: @agelosnm The frequency of checks is defined by how often you pull metrics ([scrape_config/scrape_interval](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/)) and evaluate rules ([rule_group/interval](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/)). These are configured in Prometheus. Alertmanager has [route/repeat_interval](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#route) which defines how often you are getting reminded of an existing alert. This does not _check_ uptime, it simply sends you a reminder. Check all these.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful comments! A lot of things cleared in my mind.
Regarding, the initial question, indeed I had group intervals enabled at 10s hence the service was sending messages all the time! I disabed it and evertyhing seem ok. Thank you once again! :D